# Div hover isn't working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a problem with a div when I hover div (one) the div (two) pop up but when I hover the pop up div he disappears, I need to div(two) slide or pop up before div (one) not after. And div (one) and div(two) belog to the same class.
Here is my CSS, HTML and javascript.

HTML

```
 <div id = "one" class="slideUP1"></div>
 <div id = "two" class="slideUP1"></div>
```

CSS

```
 .slideUP1

{
      background-color:Gray;
}

#one


{
    z-index:50;
    width:320px;
    height:124px;
    position:relative;
    overflow:hidden;
    float:left;
    margin-right:5px;
    margin-top:0px;
}

#two 
{ 
  display: none; 
  position:absolute;
  height:300px;
  width:900px; 
  z-index:55; 
  margin-bottom:0px;
}
```

javascript

```
$(document).ready(function () {

           $(".slideUP1").hover(function () {
               $(this).next("#two").animate({ opacity: "show", top: "144" }, "fast");
           });
       });

       $(document).ready(function () {

           $(".slideUP1").mouseleave(function () {
               $(this).next("#two").animate({ opacity: "hide", top: "154" }, "fast");
           });
       });
```

Comment: if you leave div1 and hover div2 the mouseleave on div1 is fired.
why do you use a nested $(document).ready ?

Comment: Do you want div2 to overlay div1? Your question is confusing.

Comment: why dont you use id instead of class in JS as selector?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that when you hover on the second div, you leave the first div hence making it close. Put both of them in a container and use the hover events on it instead.

```
<div id = "container">
    <div id = "one" class="slideUP1"></div>
    <div id = "two" class="slideUP1"></div>
</div>
```

And the javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

       $("#container").hover(
            function () {
               $(this).find("#two").animate({ opacity: "show", top: "144" }, "fast");
           },
            function () {
               $(this).find("#two").animate({ opacity: "hide", top: "154" }, "fast");
           });
   });
```

Comment: I tried with a container but I did not change in javascrip (next to find) and did not work. Now I it's working. I'm new to JavaScript, so I did not know. Thank you very much :)

Comment: next() returns the very next element of the subject while find() returns the elements matching the selector that are INSIDE the subject. This is why next was working without a container, but not on it.