# Opening a div on hover, then keeping div open while hovering over div

Tags: jquery

Sorry about the title to this question, it's not very clear but wasn't sure how to describe it!

Basically the problem I'm having is this. I am working on an enrolment form for training courses. There are a number of help images which open up a div on hover with additional information. What I need is for the help box to stay open if you hover over the div itself. At the moment the div closes when you move away from the help image, which makes it impossible to click on any links within the box. I want the div to stay open when hovering over either the help image or the div, but close when you move away onto another part of the page.

The HTML is here:

```
<a href="#" id="pohelplink" class="helplinks">
 <img src="images/help.png" class="helpimage" id="pohelpimage" />
</a>
<div class="helpbox" id="pohelp">
 <h4>Purchase Order</h4>
 <p>If your company requires purchase orders to be raised, we'll need to know the PO Number so we can include it on our invoice. Please type the number into this box.</p>
 <p>If your organisation doesn't use purchase orders then you can simply leave this area blank.</p>
</div>
```

And the Jquery:

```
$("#pohelplink").hover(function(){
 $("#pohelplink").css({"z-index":"1110"});
 $("#pohelp").fadeIn();
 },
function(){
 $("#pohelp").fadeOut();
 $("#pohelplink").css({"z-index":"1095"});
});
```

Any help much appreciated.

P.S. The change to the z-index is to keep the help image visible when the help div pops up, as the two overlap. I don't think it will be relevant to this particular problem, but wanted to include it for the sake of completeness.

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12691592/div-hover-isnt-working-properly/12691900#12691900

Comment: try to add another handler for your new div ("#pohelp") on mouseover.      ("#pohelp").hover($("#pohelp").css("display","block")//something like that);

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Following code may solve your problem: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RXvqc/)

```
    $("#pohelplink, #pohelp").mouseenter(function () {// show pohelp 
        $("#pohelplink").css({
            "z-index": "1110"
        });
        $("#pohelp").fadeIn();
    });
 $("#pohelp").mouseleave(function(){ // show pohelp tile mouseleave from pohelp
       $("#pohelp").fadeOut();
      $("#pohelplink").css({"z-index":"1095"});
});​
```

Comment: This was the closest answer to the correct one that I worked out in the end. Ultimately I used the above technique, but had to incorporate ALL of the elements inside a span. I then selected that span for the .mouseleave function. Otherwise the help box disappeared when leaving the 'helplink' then reappeared again.

Answer (score 1):

See jQuery [HoverIntent Pluggin](http://cherne.net/brian/resources/jquery.hoverIntent.html) for this

Answer (score 0):

Like this

```
  $("#pohelplink,#pohelp").hover(function(){
     $("#pohelplink").css({"z-index":"1110"});
     $("#pohelp").fadeIn();
     },
    function(){
     $("#pohelp").fadeOut();
     $("#pohelplink").css({"z-index":"1095"});
    });​
```

check this [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vHWrY/)